# Display gridview columns based on user selection

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a Gridview and want to make header dynamically based on user selection.

How to create headers that's been selected from users.

Comment: set AutoGenerateColumns="True" of gridview and set the dataSource of gridview as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataTable` will help you to achieve. Please follow the code below

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

protected DataTable GetDataSource() 
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

var questions = db.ExecuteQuery<string>("select question from quiz where quizid is 123").ToList();

// Header implementation
int count = 0;
foreach (var question in questions)
{
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(question);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
    count++;
}

// Rows implementation here
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
...
dt.Rows.Add(row);

return dt;
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```